# Intermittent Green Screen of Death. Ubuntu 21.04, Gnome 3.38.5, X11, 5.11.0-36-generic kernel, AMD Ryzen 5 3400g, Gigabyte B450 DS3H mobo

Tags: graphics, amd-graphics, 21.04, amdgpu, gigabyte

Big issue here. Every couple days while working I get a seemingly random "Green Screen of Death". Green screen, locks up, SysReq Magic Key procedure doesn't work (I think). The only thing that works (so far) is powering off with the power button. Fires right back up when I start it again and behaves like nothing was wrong. The only thing I can think of that causes this is that this seems to happen when I'm under a heavy load (tons of Chrome windows, Telegram, Discord, Slack), but my CPU usage rarely ever goes over 60%. I also have 32 GB (4x8) of Corsair Vengeance LPX 3000 mhz RAM overclocked from the default levels of 2133 mhz to current levels of 2733 mhz (I haven't figured out yet how to get it higher). Unsure if RAM has anything to do with it, but it's underperforming spec, if anything. Not sure what's going on with this GSOD but I figured I'd share my specs. I'm at a complete loss for what to do/how to diagnose this issue as I'm relatively new to Linux/Ubuntu. My comp works great besides this. No other issues at all. Any thoughts on how to proceed?

Specs in images below.

[inxi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PDGT.png)

[dmidecode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNtAD.png)

[About](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKbRX.png)

Other threads

[Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/q1b9bj/intermittent_green_screen_of_death_ubuntu_2104/)

[Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2467680&p=14061653#post14061653)

---

**EDIT**

Alright, I restored my UEFI optimized defaults and enabled XMP Profile 1 instead of manually OCing my ram, but it doesn't take. It's only running at 2133 mhz (same as default). This is why I did it manually in the first place. I don't understand. Should I manually boost voltage maybe? Thoughts on why the XMP profile doesn't do anything?

[After loading optimized default UEFI settings and enabling XMP Profile 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRXWf.png)

Comment: OC is probably the cause. Ryzens are particularly picky about RAM, you're using the iGPU which depends entirely on the system's RAM, so...

Comment: Alright, I restored my UEFI defaults and enabled XMR Profile 1 (Gigabyte's version of DOCP), and it doesn't take. My RAM speed is still at its default state of 2133 mhz. I don't understand it.

Alright, I restored my UEFI optimized defaults and enabled XMR Profile 1 instead of manually OCing my ram, but it doesn't take. It's only running at 2133 mhz (same as default). This is why I did it manually in the first place. I don't understand. Should I manually boost voltage maybe? Thoughts on why the XMR profile doesn't do anything?

You can see my new ram specs in my OP edit

Comment: XMP*, not XMR. Heh.

Comment: (1) Update UEFI (2) "Manufacturer: Unknown" almost always = no good

Comment: I fully updated to UEFI F61 a few weeks ago. 

How does one remedy a "Manufacturer: Unknown" issue?

Comment: No pictures of text please all text needs to be in the body of the question.